# bumpmapping OpenTK GLcontrol

Tags: c#, shader, opentk

I have to make shaders in GLSL, I'm using OpenTK, and I'm writing in C# Windows Forms.
And i have some problems with using this shaders in my GLControl
this is my vertex shader

```
attribute vec3 tangent;
attribute vec3 binormal;
varying vec3 position;
varying vec3 lightvec;
void main()
{
gl_Position = ftransform();
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
position = gl_Vertex.xyz;
mat3 TBNMatrix = mat3(tangent, binormal, gl_Normal);
lightvec = gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - position;
lightvec *= TBNMatrix;
}
```

and this is my fragment shader

```
uniform sampler2D base;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform vec3 CAMERA_POSITION;
varying vec3 position;
varying vec3 lightvec;
void main()
{
vec3 norm = texture2D(normalMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb * 2.0 - 1.0;
vec3 baseColor = texture2D(base, gl_TexCoord[0].st).rgb;
float dist = length(lightvec);
vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightvec);
float nxDir = max(0.0, dot(norm, lightVector));
vec4 diffuse = gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * nxDir;
float specularPower = 0.0;
if(nxDir != 0.0)
{
vec3 cameraVector = normalize(CAMERA_POSITION - position.xyz);
vec3 halfVector = normalize(lightVector + cameraVector);
float nxHalf = max(0.0,dot(norm, halfVector));
specularPower = pow(nxHalf, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
}
vec4 specular = gl_LightSource[0].specular * specularPower;
gl_FragColor = gl_LightSource[0].ambient +
(diffuse * vec4(baseColor.rgb,1.0)) +
specular;
}
```

Should i use GL.Uniform()? I don't know how to use this shaders...

Comment: So you are asking how to stream data to the shader program? which part are you stuck at? and what is your CPU side code?

Comment: I don't know how to pass this kind of parameters to the shader. I only know how to pass Vector, I only know that the base is jpg, but i don't know how should look Normalmap in second shader...